Flutter 'background' is deprecated
I got this warning
'background' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use surface instead. This feature was deprecated after v3.18.0-0.1.pre.
Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement

with the following code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// light mode
ThemeData lightMode = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
    background: Colors.grey.shade300,
    primary: Colors.grey.shade200,
    secondary: Colors.grey.shade400,
    inversePrimary: Colors.grey.shade800,
  )
);

In code I call the background in the following way backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background.
How to fix it?

Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface

What?
The warning tells you that the background property is deprecated and that it should be replaced with surface.
How?

Update the ThemeData of your lightMode variable to use surface instead of background:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// light mode
ThemeData lightMode = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
    surface: Colors.grey.shade300, // `surface` instead of `background`
    primary: Colors.grey.shade200,
    secondary: Colors.grey.shade400,
    inversePrimary: Colors.grey.shade800,
  )
);


Use surface instead of background:

Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface

